# how to cancel the rightclick menu event in pysimplegui

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, pysimplegui

I am using pysimplegui as my UI framework
my UI has 4 image elements in which i display feeds from camera,i have designed right click menu such that it has the camera names which i can assign to these images elements
but i see that when a right click menu is opened/clicked the image element doesn't update anymore until the menu is closed

so my question is there a way where the right click menu is opened and it doesn't affect the updates for the UI that the images still updates when new images are ready

Note the images feeds are from multiprocesses, the feeds updates every second

i am new to UI building

i have tried pyautogui to perform a click event of different buttons which closes the right clicked menu ex esc,alt,left click,middle but these button have different meaning so it create buggy effect

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point is how you update those Image elements ?

Here, I have three ways for it, first two not work for you, but the third should work.

1. loop by timeout event, right click menu will block at the `window.read` code.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

count = 0
right_click_menu = ['&Right', ['Insert', 'Delete', 'Copy', 'Edit']]

sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 16))
layout = [[sg.Text(size=100, key='LINE', right_click_menu=right_click_menu)]]
window = sg.Window("Demo", layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read(timeout=20)

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT:
        count = ((count + 1) % 101)
        window['LINE'].update('█'*count)

window.close()
```

2. Using multi-thread, the same,  right click menu will block at the `window.read` code.

```py
from time import sleep
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def counter():
    global count
    count = ((count + 1) % 101)
    print(count)
    window.write_event_value("Update", None)
    sleep(0.02)
    window.perform_long_operation(counter, "Update")

count = 1
right_click_menu = ['&Right', ['Insert', 'Delete', 'Copy', 'Edit']]

sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 16))
layout = [
    [sg.Input('', size=100, disabled=True, key='LINE', right_click_menu=right_click_menu),
     sg.Text("000", size=3, key='Number', right_click_menu=right_click_menu)],
]
window = sg.Window("Demo", layout, finalize=True)
window.perform_long_operation(counter, "Update")

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "Update":
        window['LINE'].update('█'*count)
        window['Number'].update(f'{count:0>3d}')

window.close()
```

3. Using tkinter code, `window.TKroot.after` to loop your event.

```py
from time import sleep
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def counter():
    global count
    count = ((count + 1) % 101)
    window['LINE'].update('█'*count)
    window['Number'].update(f'{count:0>3d}')
    window.TKroot.after(20, counter)

count = 0
right_click_menu = ['&Right', ['Insert', 'Delete', 'Copy', 'Edit']]

sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 16))
layout = [
    [sg.Input('', size=100, disabled=True, key='LINE', right_click_menu=right_click_menu),
     sg.Text("000", size=3, key='Number', right_click_menu=right_click_menu)],
]
window = sg.Window("Demo", layout, finalize=True)
window.TKroot.after(20, counter)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

Comment: yes the third one seems,what i want thanks

Comment: Hi,Jason is it possible to pass parameters to the function as well using the 3rd method

Comment: Using Lambda function if you need to pass some arguments when call the function. like `window.TKroot.after(20, lambda x=10, y=20: counter(x, y))` where 10, 20 is the arguments if you need it.